# Permanent focus for tool window

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way of creating a tool window in WinForms that as long as the hosting form has focus, the tool window does as well? An example of this is in Paint.NET:

[image: Focused tool window]

I'm using C# as the backend application language, under .Net 4.0.

Comment: What makes you think that it always has the focus? It doesn't. Once you click inside the main window the focus is gone. Are you trying to hide the visualization of the focused window? Because thats the difference i can see regarding these tool windows.

Comment: I must be naive then. All of the tool windows have the focussed look to them. Controls in the tool windows also seem to pick up hover events correctly

Comment: Thats what i meant with visualization. They look focused. But the don't react to keyboard focus anymore, can be tested with the color window and the combobox. Have you tried setting the owner to the mainwindow and giving the tool window style?

Comment: Yes I have. Once I do that, the tool windows can't leave the bounds of the parent form and they get the MDIChild look to them. Both of these behaviours don't happen with Paint.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code for an old version of Paint.Net is available at [openpdn Fork of Paint.NET 3.36.7](https://code.google.com/p/openpdn/source/browse#hg/src)

I tried to extract their methods from that source code into the most concise working example I could muster:

Pinvoking class:

```
internal static class Win32 {
  public const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x006;
  public const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x01C;
  public const int WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x086;

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
  internal static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg,
                                             IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  internal extern static bool PostMessageW(IntPtr handle, uint msg,
                                           IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
```

Base Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private bool ignoreNcActivate = false;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    switch (m.Msg) {
      case Win32.WM_NCACTIVATE:
        if (m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero) {
          if (ignoreNcActivate) {
            ignoreNcActivate = false;
          } else {
            Win32.SendMessageW(this.Handle, Win32.WM_NCACTIVATE, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
          }
        }
        break;
      case Win32.WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
        if (m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero) {
          Win32.PostMessageW(this.Handle, Win32.WM_NCACTIVATE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
          foreach (Form2 f in this.OwnedForms.OfType<Form2>()) {
            f.ForceActiveBar = false;
            Win32.PostMessageW(f.Handle, Win32.WM_NCACTIVATE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
          }
          ignoreNcActivate = true;
        } else if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(1)) {
          Win32.SendMessageW(this.Handle, Win32.WM_NCACTIVATE, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
          foreach (Form2 f in this.OwnedForms.OfType<Form2>()) {
            f.ForceActiveBar = true;
            Win32.SendMessageW(f.Handle, Win32.WM_NCACTIVATE, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
          }
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnShown(e);
    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.Show(this);
  }
}
```

Always active Form2 (unless app is not active):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {
  internal bool ForceActiveBar { get; set; }

  public Form2() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    this.ForceActiveBar = true;
  }

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == Win32.WM_NCACTIVATE) {
      if (this.ForceActiveBar && m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero) {
        Win32.SendMessageW(this.Handle, Win32.WM_NCACTIVATE, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no need to set TopMost to true for Form2 since it should be *owned* by the main form when it gets displayed.  Also, Form2 *is not* an MDI child form.

Comment: This is a lot like what my solution is ending up like! I'm stuck with something weird where the parent form becomes inactive when you click on the child form. I solved this by forcing focus on the parent form but it means I can't use dropdowns on the child

Comment: This is the approach I used to get as close as possible to the solution, so I'm marking it as the answer

Comment: @Darkzaelus I couldn't reproduce that focus problem.  My parent and my child forms both stay focused or both unfocused when leaving the app.

Comment: It might be because I'm using DevExpress' RibbonForm. The project has been put on hold but I'll try to remember to update when I start work on it again

Answer (score 2):

The tool windows in Paint.NET are just that—tool windows. In Win32 terms, you achieve this by creating the window with the [`WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) extended window style:

> The window is intended to be used as a floating toolbar. A tool window has a title bar that is shorter than a normal title bar, and the window title is drawn using a smaller font. A tool window does not appear in the taskbar or in the dialog that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB.

In WinForms, this is controlled by the [`FormBorderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) property. Set it to either `FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow` or `FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow` in your form's constructor.

You also need to make sure that you specify an owner window for the tool window. Its owner should be your main form, the one for which it serves as a tool palette. You generally do this when showing the form, using the overload of the [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) method that allows you to specify an owner window.

Finally, another cool effect that Paint.NET has (I think, if I remember correctly) is that the tool windows can never actually receive the focus. You can interact with them, clicking on buttons to select tools, but you can't actually set the focus to a floating palette. It always goes back to the main window. A naive attempt to emulate this behavior might be to reset the focus in one of the focus-changing notifications (e.g., the `Activate` event), but that's not a good idea for numerous reasons. A better solution would be to add the [`WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) extended window style. I'm not aware of any property that exposes this functionality in WinForms, but you can set it manually during the window's creation by overriding the [`CreateParams`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.createparams.aspx) property. For example:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    // ... other code ...

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;

            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
            return cp;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the owner means that it can't leave the bounds of the parent, which Paint.NET's toolbar's can. They also gain the "MDIChild" look, which is not what I want. I think I've found some code out that will do what I want, but it's full on WinAPI calls and goto calls. Yuck.

Comment: @Dark You seem to be confusing MDI children and owned windows. There's nothing preventing an owned window from being moved outside of the bounds of its owner. All system-generated message boxes are owned windows, and they can be moved all over the screen.

Comment: I must have done some weird combination of styles! You're right, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Windows Forms has a built-in feature for this, but you can achieve what you want with the code below:

**For main form:**

```
private ToolForm m_toolForm;

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_toolForm = new ToolForm ();
    m_toolForm.Show();
}

private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (WindowState)
    {
        case FormWindowState.Minimized:
            m_toolForm.Hide();
            break;

        case FormWindowState.Maximized:
            m_toolForm.Show();
            break;
    }
}
```

**For tool form:**
You don't need any code, just set the property "TopMost" to true.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't do anything for my situation. If you cilck away from on the tool form, it loses focus

Answer (score 0):

For those using the DevExpress RibbonForm, please use the solution in the below link to solve the focus problem. The zip file is in a comment to the solution, not in the solution itself:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q498321